# Color Dependent Bar Graph in R

Tags: r, matrix, colors, bar-chart, graphing

I'm a bit out of my depth with this one here.  I have the following code that generates two equally sized matrices:

```
MAX<-100
m<-5
n<-40

success<-matrix(runif(m*n,0,1),m,n)
samples<-floor(MAX*matrix(runif(m*n),m))+1
```

the `success` matrix is the probability of success and the `samples` matrix is the corresponding number of samples that was observed in each case.  I'd like to make a bar graph that groups each column together with the height being determined by the `success` matrix.  The color of each bar needs to be a color (scaled from `1` `to` `MAX`) that corresponds to the number of observations  (i.e., small samples would be more red, for instance, whereas high samples would be green perhaps).

Any ideas?

Comment: So do you want a stacked bar graph, where each layer in the stack corresponds to a row in your matrix?  It isn't obvious how you intend to plot your 3d matrix (rows, cols, value) in what is essentially a 2d format (x location, y height).

Comment: I'd like to have the rows of the success matrix be grouped by row...so, the bar graph would have 40 groups of heights, with 5 bars per group.  I'd like each bar to be color coded to a value between 1 and MAX (100).  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @BrodieG's `data.long`, this plot might be a little easier to interpret.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)   # for brewer.pal(...)
ggplot(data.long) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=success, fill=count),colour="grey70",stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(9,"RdYlGn")) +
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

[image]

Note that actual values are probably different because you use random numbers in your sample. In future, consider using `set.seed(n)` to generate reproducible random samples.

**Edit** [Response to OP's comment]

You get numbers for x-axis and facet labels because you start with matrices instead of data.frames. So convert `success` and `samples` to data.frames, set the column names to whatever your test names are, and prepend a `group` column with the "list of factors". Converting to long format is a little different now because the first column has the group names.

```
library(reshape2)
set.seed(1)
success <- data.frame(matrix(runif(m*n,0,1),m,n))
success <- cbind(group=rep(paste("Factor",1:nrow(success),sep=".")),success)
samples <- data.frame(floor(MAX*matrix(runif(m*n),m))+1)
samples <- cbind(group=success$group,samples)
data.long <- cbind(melt(success,id=1), melt(samples, id=1)[3])
names(data.long) <- c("group", "x", "success", "count")
```

One way to set a threshold color is to add a column to `data.long` and use that for `fill`:

```
threshold <- 25
data.long$fill <- with(data.long,ifelse(count>threshold,max(count),count))
```

Putting it all together:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(data.long) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=success, fill=fill),colour="grey70",stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(9,"RdYlGn")) +
  facet_grid(group~.)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,hjust=0,vjust=0.4))
```

[image]

Finally, when you have names for the x-axis labels they tend to get jammed together, so I rotated the names -90°.

Comment: Excellent. Can you arbitrarily change the threshold for the color green? In other words, make it so that any 'count' above 25 is green, and the rest of the color continuum is between 25 and 0?  And is there a way to replace the indices on the bottom and right axes with a vector of characters?  I have test names for the bottom and a list of factors for the right axes.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Are there any books or resources you can recommend to get to the level you guys are at with this language?  As you can see, my rudimentary understanding is just enough to get into trouble or stranded halfway through projects!  :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `ggplot`.  First, get data into long format with melt:

```
library(reshape2)
data.long <- cbind(melt(success), melt(samples)[3])
names(data.long) <- c("group", "x", "success", "count")
head(data.long)
#   group x    success count
# 1     1 1 0.48513473     8
# 2     2 1 0.56583802    58
# 3     3 1 0.34541582    40
# 4     4 1 0.55829073    64
# 5     5 1 0.06455401    37
# 6     1 2 0.88928606    78
```

Note `melt` will iterate through the row/column combinations of both matrices the same way, so we can just `cbind` the resulting molten data frames.  The `[3]` after the second `melt` is so we don't end up with repeated group and x values (we only need the counts from the second `melt`).  Now let `ggplot` do its thing:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.long, aes(x=x, y=success, group=group, fill=count)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low="red", mid="yellow", high="green", 
    midpoint=mean(data.long$count)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: That's great.  Can they be forced to be beside each other, like the beside=TRUE parameter in barplot?

Comment: @user3033594 try `position="dodge"` inside `geom_bar()`, though if you do that it gets harder to tell what the x value is.  Also, if you do that you will have 200 bars, which gets difficult to distinguish.  Is that really what you want?